# Identifying indexes in an array that haven't been used

Tags: c#, indexing

OK so I have created an array of four buttons, when one of the buttons is clicked the background colour will change and the value of that button will be stored in a variable. however, if another button is clicked then I want the button that was clicked originally to revert back to the background colour it was originally, while the new button will change its background colour. I.e. only one button at a time will be 'selected'. at the minute i have this:

```
btn[0].BackColor = Color.DimGray;
btn[1].BackColor = Color.DimGray;
btn[2].BackColor = Color.DimGray;
btn[3].BackColor = Color.DimGray;
btn[selectedIndex].BackColor = Color.Lime;
```

I was wondering if there is a way for me to isolate the Indexes that aren't selected and setting them all back to the same colour without having to repaeat the same line of code multiple times, i only ask because there are 17 more buttons on the interface and it just looks horrible.

Comment: Store the current "selectedIndex" variable in a private field in the form as "oldSelectedIndex", then you only have to change two, `btn[selectedIndex]` and `btn[oldSelectedIndex]`, the other ones you can leave as is. Set `oldSelectedIndex = selectedIndex` at the bottom of the function.

Comment: @RonBeyer but that wont change the colour of the previous index back to the original background colour? not to mention if i need to use that index again wont that cause a problem?

Comment: @RonBeyer oh sorry i didnt fully understand that until i read it again, i will give that a go! Thanks!

Comment: I would try it out, it avoids 18 unnecessary property settings since you really only need to modify 2 buttons. Also initialize `oldSelectedIndex` to 0 or something valid in the array.

Comment: Have you considered using radio buttons with [`Appearance`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.radiobutton.appearance%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) set to [`Button`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.appearance(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: @JoeFarrell yes I have but the appearance of the buttons available with radio buttons isn't suitable for the interface I am creating, the max height can't be changed when I tried it so having to do it this way

Comment: @DeanLewis: A radio button's `AutoSize` property will be set to `true` by default. If you set it to `false`, then you can change its dimensions however you like.

Comment: @JoeFarrell ah thanks! I didn't notice that one in the settings! If I can't get this way to work I will definitely give that a go!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set them all in a single `for` loop, like this:

```
for (var i = 0 ; i != btn.Length ; i++) {
    btn[i].BackColor = (i == selectedIndex)
                     ? Color.Lime
                     : Color.DimGray;
}
```

The conditional inside the loop compares `i`, the current index, to `selectedIndex`, and determines if the button's background is to be set to lime or dim gray.